# Query JSON Array with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3 i have a JSON column in a postgres database called _days.

I try to query as shown below:

```
$day=3
//_days = '[true,false,false,true,true,false,true]'
$query->where('_days->'.$day,'true')->first();
```

What I am trying to do is to check if the index 3 of the json array is true.
Unfortunately it returns **null**.

When getting the sql of the eloquent query I found out that it generates the following SQL:

```
select * 
from "table" 
where "_days"->>'3' = true
```

This of course does not work because it is trying to find the key '3' where there is non.

The query I am trying to get is:

```
select * 
from "table" 
where "_days"->>3 = true
```

How can I achieve this withought recurring to creating a raw query and just using eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create a collection out of the JSON column and just get the day with the index 3 like this

```php
collect(json_decode('[true,false,false,true,true,false,true]'))->get($day)
```